# How to change magento shipment email template payment Method block

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I am using magneto 1.9. How to i have change magento shipment email template payment Method block?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found found solution for payment block.

For change payment block need following below steps:

Step 1. Copy app\design\frontend\base\default\template\paygate\info\cc.phtml to app\design\frontend[Your Package][Your Theme]\template\paygate\info\cc.phtml

Step 2. Change here that you want to change

Step 3- Save

Answer (score 0):

If you want to render a specific text/html for a particular payment method in shipment email template only then you have to override `sendEmail` function of `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment` class and play with `$paymentBlockHtml` variable.

In that function, you can add a condition like

```
if($order->getPayment()->getMethod()=='cashondelivery'){
    $paymentBlockHtml = Mage::helper('sales')->__('Payment after delivery');
}
```

[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for answers but i have got solution for payment method block.